# C++ with SmartHeap on Amazon Linux 2023, SIGSEGV when any exception that suppose to be caught is thrown

Tags: malloc, heap-memory, libstdc++

C++ application with SmartHeap fail to throw exception on Amazon Linux 2023

## stack back trace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7cac95c in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e9b976 in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff7cad2fc in __cxa_throw () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000000000400e18 in f(int) ()
#4  0x0000000000400e8c in main ()


 ldd ./ii8.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffde0d8000)
        libsmartheap_smp64.so => /home/vagrant/ctm_em/lib/libsmartheap_smp64.so (0x00007fb723080000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb722e00000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb722d25000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb723060000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb722a00000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb72305b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb72319a000)
```

ls -l /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Mar 11 03:40 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

same application not linked with SmartHeap, but uses native malloc implementation works as expected

Any idea what can cause this behavior, what was changed in latest runtime revision regarding EH that can explain the SIGSEGV

thanks,
Eyal

I did try with libstdc++.so.6.0.19  and it works fine, it seems that something break in between to libstdc++.so.6.0.29